# Is there a common notation for $x \sqcap Yy\neq \bot$

Tags: notation, order-theory, lattice-orders

Is there a commonly used shorthand to express the following relation:

$x R y \iff X \sqcap Y \neq \bot$?

That is, the greatest lower bound of the two elements is not bottom.

In terms of sets, the relation holds when $x$ and $y$ are not disjoint.

I use this concept in an academic poster I'm making, and I'd like to know if there's already a standard operator/notation to express this, before I make my own shorthand.

Comment: Why not use the set definition if you think people won't know the notation? $xRy \Leftrightarrow x \cap y \neq \emptyset$

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish I'm mostly worried about succinctness, and being constrained for space. It's less that I'm worried people won't know the notation, and more I'm worried there's a notation people do know that I don't.